# AppleScript - How to click a UI element without Actions

Tags: applescript, automator

You can click a button easily by use "click", or "AXPress", "AXShowMenu", "AXOpen". But for UI element without Action, None of these methods worked.

Like some "Image", or "Group", you can set its state to select by clicking the left mouse button or call up the menu by clicking the right mouse button. But "Actions" for these Image or Group is empty, and they don't respond to any send event in Applescript like "click"(click at position also).

I used Automator to record click events, the transfer code in Automator is:
"set uiScript to "click image 22 of group 1 of scroll area 1 of application process 1"
the "click" it uses take effect.
then I tried record left click and right click the image, and all the code in Automator is exactly the same, I don't know how it distinguishes between a left click and a right click, there must be some other mechanism.

Comment: What is it exactly your are trying to click, what _application_ and which _UI elements_? (Screenshot of the **Watch Me Do** events, if you think that would help.)

Comment: I had a similar problem / phenomenon when I Automator-recorded selecting several letters of a word (e.g.: 7 times left-arrow) but was pushed to the realization that non-char "characters" (left-arrow with me, maybe left-button with you?) are nevertheless INVISIBLE parts of an Automator "string". Try copy-pasting and exchanging "left-click" and "right-click" to find out …